# How to execute Shell script in Linux?

Tags: java, linux, bash, ethereum

I am trying to write a Java code which can be used on Windows and Linux machine to generate bytecode for Ethereum contracts.

I am not familiar with shell scripts and linux, from what I read on internet I would be able to execute the following batch file via bash...but unfortunately i got it not working. What is the problem with my code which is meant for windows and linux and generates a batch file for windows and a shell file for linux.

How should the code be for linux? On windows this code works like a charm.

```
        String delim="";
        String scriptName="";
        String cmd="";
        if (Linux) {
            delim = "/";
            scriptName="compile.sh";
            cmd = "bash /c compile.sh";
        }
        else {
            delim = "\\";
            scriptName="compile.bat";
            cmd = "cmd /c compile.bat";
        }


        String UUID = __SolidityFile.getValue(getContext(),"__UUID__");
        String firstFolder = UUID.substring(0, 2);
        String secondFolder = UUID.substring(2, 4);
        String secondFolderLocation=com.mendix.core.Core.getConfiguration().getBasePath()+delim+"data"+delim+"files"+delim + firstFolder+ delim + secondFolder ;
        String fileLocation=secondFolderLocation+ delim + UUID;
        Core.getLogger("Solidity").info(fileLocation);

        String solc =com.mendix.core.Core.getConfiguration().getResourcesPath()+delim+"node"+delim+"node_modules"+delim+"solc"+delim+"solcjs";
        String node=com.mendix.core.Core.getConfiguration().getResourcesPath()+delim+"node.exe";

        try {
              //  Block of code to try
            final File file = new File(secondFolderLocation+delim+scriptName);
            file.createNewFile();
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file, "UTF-8");
            writer.println("cd "+secondFolderLocation);
            writer.println(node+" "+ solc +" " +UUID +" --bin");
            writer.println("exit");
            writer.close();
            Process p =  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, null, new File(secondFolderLocation));
            p.waitFor();
            //file.delete();

            String byteCodeFile = "";
            String byteFileType = ByteCodeType.getCaption();

            switch (byteFileType) {
            case "TestToken": 
                 byteCodeFile =  fileLocation+"_TESTTOKEN.bin" ;
                 break;

            case "SafeMath": 
                 byteCodeFile =  fileLocation+"_SafeMath.bin" ;
                 break;

            case "Owned": 
                 byteCodeFile =  fileLocation+"_Owned.bin" ;
                 break;

            case "ERC20Interface": 
                 byteCodeFile =  fileLocation+"_ERC20Interface.bin" ;
                 break;

            case "ApproveAndCallFallBack": 
                 byteCodeFile =  fileLocation+"_ApproveAndCallFallBack.bin" ;
                 break;  
            }

            Core.getLogger("Solidity").info(byteCodeFile);
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner( new File(byteCodeFile), "UTF-8" );
            String text = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
            scanner.close();
            return text;



    }
        catch(Exception e) {
              //  Block of code to handle errors
            return null ;
            }
```

Comment: What do you want the bash command to do?  What is the full command for Windows?  Is `cmd /c compile.bat` the whole thing?  If it is, likely all you need is `bash compile.sh`.  That `/c` isn't going to do anything for you.  I don't know what the scope of the java program is, so if you can tell me what you want the bash to do, you can likely get it the rest of the way there in java.

Answer (score 1):

Try do it:

When is Linux environment:

Remove `bash /c`

```
cmd = "/usr/local/bin/compile.sh";
```

You need another environment condition(if) to run the code below:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
Process p = pb.start();
```

Please, try it and let me know

***My code***

File opt/development/workspace/testes/src/testes/Main.java

```
package testes;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String cmd = "/opt/development/workspace/testes/src/testes/script.sh";

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);

        Process p = pb.start();

        System.out.println(p);
    }

}
```

File script.sh

```
mkdir stackoverfllow
```

The folder has been created in /opt/development/workspace/testes

Comment: got this error now:

```Cannot run program "/home/vcap/app/model/resources/install.sh": error=13, Permission denied
```

How can i give read write execute rights when making a file? after it or while making it?

Comment: `chmod u+x /home/vcap/app/model/resources/install.sh`
Explanation: `u` ->current user; `+` -> add; `x`->execute

Comment: @kenny_k thanks for additional information ... I forgot that